# how to use array in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a db table which has an integer array. But how can I add this field in my model? I tried writing it using `IntegerField` but on save it is giving error

```
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list
```

How can I add this field to my model? I am using this field in my views.py so I need to add it in my model. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the datatype in your database? What database are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may be interested in using a [`CommaSeparatedIntegerField`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#commaseparatedintegerfield).

If you've got a list of integers like this:

```
my_ints = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

and a model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    values = CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length = 200)
```

then you can save `my_ints` into a `MyModel` like this:

```
m = MyModel(values = ','.join(my_ints))
m.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would look into [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). In particular, your database is not even in 1st normal form, the first and probably most significant of the normal forms which states that normalized data should not contain any repeating groups. As a result, the Django object-relational-mapper will have considerable difficulty modeling your data.

By supporting only single, non-repeating types, Django in a sense enforces 1st normal form in data. You could try to write your own SQL to manage this particular field or perhaps find some code on the internet, but perhaps better would be to refactor this field into a many-to-one relationship in its own model. You can find Django documentation on this [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#many-to-one-relationships).

Answer (score 1):

Clueless' answer is probably the best you can get, but in case you still want to store array of numbers in single field, you can do this - either by manually e.g. pickling it and then storing to TextField, or by writing custom model field that do something like this for you automatically.

Here's the doc: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/howto/custom-model-fields/

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by saying textfield in my model.Since i am only using that field for reading it doesnot effect me